# text grouped style in sidewaystable

Tags: tables, rotating, tabularx

I have a problem with my `sidewaystable`. I have quite a lot text in one of my columns. I have used `tabularx` so that the text doesn't run out of the page at the right side. Now the text is in grouped style which looks odd and I would like to have it left-aligned. When I use `{llllll}` there is no word-wrap anymore so the text runs out of the page again.

What can I do? Does anyone have an idea?

This is my table:

```
\begin{sidewaystable}
\caption{Darstellung anderer Studien zur MMN/MMR bei depressiven Patienten}


\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{llXXXX}
\toprule 
Studie & Verfahren & Patienten N & Medikation & Deviants & Ergebnisse\\
\toprule
Ogura 1993 & EEG & 36 Depression und Bipolare Störung & keine & Frequenz(Std 1000 Hz, Dev 2000 Hz), ISI: 1.5 $\pm 0.1$ s & verringerte MMN \\\\

Umbricht 2003 & EEG & 22 Depression & vermutlich ja & Dauer- und Frequenz-Deviants & Keine veränderte MMN\\\\

Kähkönen 2007 & EEG+MEG & 13, Depression, in akuter Episode & keine & 10 \% und 20 \% Frequenz-Deviants + „neue/komplexe Töne“ & erhöhte MMN bei 10\%-Frequenz-Deviants\\\\

Takei 2009 & MEG & 14, Depression in akuter Episode & ja & Dauer-Deviants (Std 50 ms, Dev: 100 ms) , Frequenz (Std: 1000 Hz, Dev 1200 Hz) Vokal-Deviants (Std:a/Dev:o), ISI: 445 $\pm$ 15 ms & verringerte mGFP der MMNm\\\\

He 2010 & EEG & 22 TRD-Patienten & keine Medikation ab 72 h vor Testung & Frequenz-Deviants (Std: 1100 Hz, Dev: 1200 Hz), ISI: 0.625 s, Dauer: 50 ms & erhöhte MMN\\\\

Qiao 2013 & EEG & 24, erste Episode & keine & Dauer-Deviants (Std: 50 ms, Dev:150 ms/ Std: 150 ms, Dev: 50 ms), Frequenz 700 Hz, ISI: 1000 ms & verringerte fronto-zentrale MMN-Amplitude bei Dev: 150 ms, MMN-Amplituden-peak-latency länger\\

\bottomrule 

\end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you meant with "the text is in grouped style", but I assumed that you meant that there are some wide blank spaces between words dut to know problems in narrow columns. To prevent this, you can use a new column type with `\raggedright` for the `X` columns (you could also use `\RaggedRight` after loading `ragged2e`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\caption{Darstellung anderer Studien zur MMN/MMR bei depressiven Patienten}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{llYYYY}
\toprule 
Studie & Verfahren & Patienten N & Medikation & Deviants & Ergebnisse\\\\
\toprule
Ogura 1993 & EEG & 36 Depression und Bipolare Störung & keine & Frequenz(Std 1000 Hz, Dev 2000 Hz), ISI: 1.5 $\pm 0.1$ s & verringerte MMN \\\\    
Umbricht 2003 & EEG & 22 Depression & vermutlich ja & Dauer- und Frequenz-Deviants & Keine veränderte MMN\\\\    
Kähkönen 2007 & EEG+MEG & 13, Depression, in akuter Episode & keine & 10 \% und 20 \% Frequenz-Deviants + „neue/komplexe Töne“ & erhöhte MMN bei 10\%-Frequenz-Deviants\\\\    
Takei 2009 & MEG & 14, Depression in akuter Episode & ja & Dauer-Deviants (Std 50 ms, Dev: 100 ms) , Frequenz (Std: 1000 Hz, Dev 1200 Hz) Vokal-Deviants (Std:a/Dev:o), ISI: 445 $\pm$ 15 ms & verringerte mGFP der MMNm\\\\    
He 2010 & EEG & 22 TRD-Patienten & keine Medikation ab 72 h vor Testung & Frequenz-Deviants (Std: 1100 Hz, Dev: 1200 Hz), ISI: 0.625 s, Dauer: 50 ms & erhöhte MMN\\\\
Qiao 2013 & EEG & 24, erste Episode & keine & Dauer-Deviants (Std: 50 ms, Dev:150 ms/ Std: 150 ms, Dev: 50 ms), Frequenz 700 Hz, ISI: 1000 ms & verringerte fronto-zentrale MMN-Amplitude bei Dev: 150 ms, MMN-Amplituden-peak-latency länger\\

\bottomrule 
\end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

[image]